# Tag merge request: [windows-api] and others into [winapi] on SO

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request

`[winapi]` - 2503 questions
<strike>`[windows-api]` - 30 questions</strike>
<strike>`[win32api]` - 2 questions</strike> (Completed Mar 5/2010)
<strike>`[win32-api]` - 62 questions</strike> (Completed Mar 5/2010 while waiting for Chinese food to arrive lol)
<strike>`[window]` AND `[api]` - 3 questions ( "" )</strike>
<strike>`[windows]` AND `[api]` - 114 questions (likely needs hand-sorting)</strike> (Completed Mar 20/2010)

Proposed:
`[win32]` - 835 questions

---

I'm going to leave the `[win32]` tag for now. It should probably have its own request question anyway. In finishing this up, I only removed that tag from only a couple of questions, so that may indicate it was used instead of `[winapi]`.

Comment: Does win32 always refer to the same thing? It does to me.

Comment: @Brian: Good point. Edited. Also added `[win32-api]` to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have completed this request by hand, including another 5 questions with `[windows-api]` that popped up since I last went through these.

Comment: +1 for `while waiting for Chinese food to arrive lol`

Answer (score 1):

Done

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what to do with the `[win32]` tag.

I think most of the questions tagged with it refer to Win32-API, but it is also used in situations where it doesn't refer to that. There are 165 questions tagged with `[windows]` AND `[win32]`, which is few enough to skim through and manually re-tag where necessary. That would at least help a little in the cleanup process, though it probably won't catch everything.