# What is the SO team's workflow for fixing bugs and implementing new features? How could it be improved?

Tags: discussion, bug-reports, feature-request-process

Playing off [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48268/is-there-a-way-to-appeal-status-by-design-decisions) a little bit, I'd like to know how the SO team prioritizes and processes requests such as fixing bugs and implementing new features.

It strikes me that the current system is a bit 'loose', where things are fixed or implemented on a whim. This may or may not *actually* be true, and I'm not saying there's anything inherently wrong with the current system, but at the same time, I think there is room for improvement.

In particular, sometimes there may be hidden or higher motivations for some decisions, which I think should be explained and/or discussed, sometimes in far greater detail than has been exposed in the past. What are these motivations, and how do they relate to the overall vision for the sites? If the community knows more about these motivations, we can collectively solve the problem in a way that meets everyone's needs.

How can we improve the current process to better satisfy both the community and its leaders?

Comment: Jeff's comment here also applied: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2832/details-about-the-flagging-mechanism/2837#2837 The ball representing a bug this time.

Comment: Would you be comfortable with 17,605 users commenting on your dev skills and finding ways to get you to do a better job?  Don't mess with a Good Thing, you'll ruin it.

Comment: @nobugz: Yes: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43683/retagging-accountability-request-closed and I'm not alone: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39405/moderator-accountability-request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In particular, **sometimes there may be hidden or higher motivations for some decisions**, which I think should be explained and/or discussed, sometimes in far greater detail than has been exposed in the past. What are these motivations, and how do they relate to the overall vision for the sites? If the community knows more about these motivations, we can collectively solve the problem in a way that meets everyone's needs.

Oh, you want to know the *secrets!* Well why didn't you just ask? First, of course, you'll have to be indoctrinated into our secret decision making cabal society, and I can't reveal how that is done.

But seriously, it's difficult to answer this when it is predicated on "please reveal your hidden motivations".

I think we've been extremely transparent, and I personally hate having secrets. I would rather everything be out in the open. So

- I am the wrong person to ask, as I don't even *like* secrets
- I really don't know what you mean, unless you can refer to specific "secrets" you think we've withheld for some hypothetical and possibly imaginary reason.

Comment: Oh, I've already discussed your hidden motivations: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42628/vote-count-is-off-and-why-jeff-is-trying-to-destroy-all-bacon

Comment: Eh, it's not about secrets. It's about the vision for the site. The team implements/fixes things based on that, but sometimes there's no explanation why a proposal doesn't fit into that vision. Lately, you've been doing a good job of adding an answer [explaining why](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7322), but some [previous](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915) [examples](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170) leave us scratching our head.