# Tag merge request: Merge [win32api] with [winapi] and make it a synonym

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

I've seen that [such a tag merge request was already put in about one year ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39015/149334).

It seems that it might have to be repeated:

- [winapi](/questions/tagged/winapi) (used 6,276 times) — seems to be the main tag. That's fine.
- [windows-api](/questions/tagged/windows-api) (also used 6,276 times) seems to be a synonym for [winapi](/questions/tagged/winapi). I suppose that's fine, too.
- **[win32api](/questions/tagged/win32api) (used 154 times) — I suppose this ought to be merged with [winapi](/questions/tagged/winapi), and installed as another synonym for [winapi](/questions/tagged/winapi).**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[win32api](/questions/tagged/win32api) is already a [synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/winapi/synonyms) of [winapi](/questions/tagged/winapi).

The questions remaining in the former tag are there because they were never merged into the latter (currently this is a manual process).

Comment: thanks for answering. Please forgive my ignorance, but would I have to request this again in a separate answer, or will someone eventually get to merging them? (Not that I'm fanatic about these two tags, I'm just curious how this process usually works.)

Comment: @stakx: Usually a mod will get to merging it eventually (maybe soon if they see this question). It's not as big a deal now because any new questions with `[win32api]` will get auto-retagged to `[winapi]`, and tag searches should get auto-remapped as well.